# Low poly terrain created by modifying geometry vertices is producing black glitches

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create random low-poly style terrain for my project. The way in which I decided would be best to do this is the following:

1. Create a `BoxGeometry` object to act as my floor, and set the `widthSegments` and the `heightSegments` to more than the default (100)
2. Use the `.vertices` array to access each vertex
3. Iterate through each vertex using a `forEach` loop on `geomFloor.vertices`
4. Each iteration, generate a random number between to points (a max and min y position for the vertex)
5. Set the current vertex's `.y` to the random number
6. Update the vertices

**Here is my code for this process:**

```
function createFloorSecondScene(){ 
    var geomFloor = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20000, 1, 20000, 100, 1, 100); 

    geomFloor.mergeVertices();

    var randomFloorVertexPos;

    geomFloor.vertices.forEach(function(floorVertex){
        randomFloorVertexPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((0) - 
        (-90)) + (-90));

        floorVertex.y = randomFloorVertexPos;
        geomFloor.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    });

    var matFloor = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 
    Colors.grassGreen});
    matFloor.flatShading = true;

    var Floor = new THREE.Mesh(geomFloor, matFloor);

    Floor.position.y = -72.5;
    Floor.receiveShadow = true;
    Floor.castShadow = true;
    Floor.name = "floor";
    scene.add(Floor);
}
```

**The Problem**

As you can see from the screenshot below, this is how I want the floor to look, and in some sections and from some angles, it does work as intended.

[image: Three.js Low Poly Working]

However, in large areas of the floor, these weird black shapes are created, but disappear when you change camera angle with `OrbitControls`.

[image: Three.js Low Poly Not Working]

I assume this is due to the simple method used to manipulate the vertices of the geometry, and that some vertices are probably overlapping which is causing them to render like this.

**What I need**

- **Main:** Fix for the black shapes
- If you can (not necessary), an explanation for why this only happens in certain places and from certain angles
- If I have manipulated the vertices in the wrong way and/or there is a better way to create a random low poly terrain like I need, I would be grateful for an explanation of the correct way to code it.

Comment: Why don't you use `PlaneGeometry` as you base geometry?

Comment: @Mugen87 Initially I didn't realise `PlaneGeometry` had width & height segments so I went with `BoxGeometry` as I knew I would be able to manipulate vertices and so just kept it, would PlaneGeometry be better? Would be an easy switch.

Comment: @Mugen87 Wow changing to `PlaneGeometry` was the fix... thanks! If you want to write a quick answer I'll accept it, if not I'll answer myself later!

Comment: @JJGerrish What are the answers to your questions?

Comment: @WestLangley Got the answer from @Mugen87, was simply the fact that I was using `BoxGeometry` instead of `PlaneGeometry` (it's accepted down below)

Comment: @JJGerrish That answer does not answer your questions. What are the answers?

Comment: @WestLangley If you're referring to me asking for an explanation for the black shapes then I did not get an answer for that, but the main point was that I was looking for a fix for the black shapes, which I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to `PlaneGeometry` should make it easier in order to generate your terrain.